# Can I use Gauss theorem in this case

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is something unclear about the following example. Namely, they used symmetry in order to calculate the surface integral by using Gauss. I tried not to use symmetry, and just put that the field is F= x^3*i, and I still got the same solution. Is it okay if I do that, or must y and z be present in F?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can do that, not all variables need occur, but what is $i$ ? Indicating the first component ?

Comment: @Peter That was my assumption in this case. If I use F=x^3, should F have only the 1st component?

Comment: It might help if you also show your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as the Divergence Theorem states

$$\oint_{x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2}\vec F(x,y,z)\cdot \hat n\,dS=\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2} \nabla \cdot \vec F(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

for suitably smooth vector fields, then clearly if $\vec F(x,y,z)=\hat x x^3$, and since $\hat n=\frac{\hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac1a (\hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz)$

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2}\vec F(x,y,z)\cdot \hat n\,dS&=\frac1a \oint_{x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2}x^4\,dS\\\\&=\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2}  3x^2\,dx\,dy\,dz
\end{align}$$

And you can finish?

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is how I have done this. I was also wondering: why do you automatically assume that $x^3$ is in direction of $\hat x $ in this case?

Comment: The theorem applies to all suitable vector fields.  Certainly, $\vec F =\hat x x^3$ qualifies.

Comment: Couldn't you then assume that $x^3$ is in direction of $\hat y$, instead of $\hat x$? But that would give a different result?

Comment: The result from setting $\vec F=\hat y x^3$ is the trivial conclusion that $0=0$.  That is all that would show here.

Comment: Then what does 'suitable field', from your previous comment, mean in this case? Is field F= $\hat x x^3$ the only one that gives the most information here?

Comment: Suitable would be a continuously differentiable vector field.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int x^{4}\,\dd S & = \int z^{4}\,\hat{r}\cdot\hat{r}\,\,\dd S =
\int\pars{{z^{4} \over r}\,\vec{r}}\cdot\
\overbrace{\dd\vec{S}\,\,\,}^{\ds{\hat{r}\ \dd S}}\ =\
\int\nabla\cdot\pars{{z^{4} \over r}\,\vec{r}}\dd^{3}\vec{r}
\\[5mm] & =
\int\braces{\bracks{{4z^{3}\,\hat{z} \over r} +
z^{4}\pars{-\,{\vec{r} \over r^{3}}}}\cdot\vec{r} +
{z^{4} \over r}\,3}\dd^{3}\vec{r} =
\int\pars{{4z^{4} \over r} - {z^{4} \over r} + {3z^{4} \over r}}\dd^{3}\vec{r}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{a}{6r^{4} \over r}
\underbrace{\pars{\int_{\Omega_{\vec{r}}}\cos^{4}\pars{\theta}
\,\dd\Omega_{\vec{r}}}}_{\ds{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{4}\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi = {4\pi \over 5}}}\ r^{2}\,\dd r
\\[5mm] & =
{4\pi \over 5}\int_{0}^{a}6r^{5}\,\dd r = \bbx{4\pi a^{6} \over 5}
\end{align}